# Using rvest to grab data returns No matches

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I'm trying to grab some election results from politco's website using rvest.

http://www.politico.com/2016-election/results/map/president/wisconsin/

I couldn't pull all the data on the page at once, so I went for a county-level approach. Each county has a unique css selector (e.g Adams County's is: '#countyAdams .results-table'). So I grabbed all the county names from elsewhere and set up a quick loop (yes I know loops are bad practice in R but I anticipated this method taking me about 3 minutes).

Grab the URL

```
wiscoSixteen <- read_html("http://www.politico.com/2016-election/results/map/president/wisconsin")
```

Create an empty data.frame (and no I didn't pre-define the columns)

```
stateDf <- NULL
```

Get the list of counties (this isn't complete but to get to the point the routine breaks we don't need all 70 counties)

```
wiscoCounties <- c("Adams", "Ashland", "Barron", "Bayfield", "Brown", "Buffalo", "Burnett", "Calumet", "Chippewa", "Clark", "Columbia", "Crawford", "Dane", "Dodge", "Door", "Douglas", "Dunn", "Eau Claire", "Florence", "Fond du Lac", "Forest", "Grant", "Green", "Green Lake", "Iowa", "Iron", "Jackson", "Jefferson", "Juneau")
```

My 'for' loop:

```
for (i in 1:length(wiscoCounties)){

    #Pull out the i'th county name and paste it in a string
    wiscoResult <- wiscoSixteen %>% html_node(paste("#county"," .results-table", sep=wiscoCounties[i])) %>% html_table()

    #add a column for the county name so I can ID later
    wiscoResult[,4] <- wiscoCounties[i]

    #then rbind 
    stateDf <- rbind(stateDf, wiscoResult)
}
```

When it gets through the 10th county it stops and returns 'Error: No matches'.

Can't find anything unique about 'Columbia', the 11th county. At a loss for what's happening. I'm sure it's something stupid as that's usually the case. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: FWIW, loops are fine. You can read the [R inferno](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf) for details as to why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, why not just use the XHR requests that end up populating those tables (I'm kinda surprised you're getting any data at all from them since they get generated from a separate data request):

```
library(httr)
library(stringi)
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

res <- GET("http://s3.amazonaws.com/origin-east-elections.politico.com/mapdata/2016/WI_20161108.xml")
dat <- readLines(textConnection(content(res, as="text")))

stri_split_fixed(dat[2], "|")[[1]] %>%
  stri_replace_last_fixed(";", "") %>% 
  stri_split_fixed(";", 3) %>% 
  map_df(~setNames(as.list(.), c("rep_id", "first", "last"))) -> candidates

dat[stri_detect_regex(dat, "^WI;P;G")] %>% 
  stri_replace_first_regex("^WI;P;G;", "") %>% 
  map_df(function(x) {

    county_results <- stri_split_fixed(x, "||", 2)[[1]]

    stri_replace_last_fixed(county_results[1], ";;", "") %>% 
      stri_split_fixed(";") %>% 
      map_df(~setNames(as.list(.), c("fips", "name", "x1", "reporting", "x2", "x3", "x4"))) -> county_prefix

    stri_split_fixed(county_results[2], "|")[[1]] %>% 
      stri_split_fixed(";") %>% 
      map_df(~setNames(as.list(.), c("rep_id", "party", "count", "pct", "x5", "x6", "x7", "x8", "candidate_idx"))) %>% 
      left_join(candidates, by="rep_id") -> df

    df$fips <- county_prefix$fips
    df$name <- county_prefix$name
    df$reporting <- county_prefix$reporting

    select(df, -starts_with("x"))

  }) -> results
```

It seems to be complete data:

```
glimpse(results)
## Observations: 511
## Variables: 10
## $ rep_id        <chr> "WI270631108", "WI270621108", "WI270691108", "WI270711108", "WI270701108", "WI270731108", "WI270721108",...
## $ party         <chr> "Dem", "GOP", "Lib", "CST", "ADP", "WW", "Grn", "Dem", "GOP", "Lib", "CST", "ADP", "WW", "Grn", "Dem", "...
## $ count         <chr> "1382210", "1409467", "106442", "12179", "1561", "1781", "30980", "3780", "5983", "207", "44", "4", "9",...
## $ pct           <chr> "46.9", "47.9", "3.6", "0.4", "0.1", "0.1", "1.1", "37.4", "59.2", "2.0", "0.4", "0.0", "0.1", "0.8", "5...
## $ candidate_idx <chr> "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7",...
## $ first         <chr> "Clinton", "Trump", "Johnson", "Castle", "De La Fuente", "Moorehead", "Stein", "Clinton", "Trump", "John...
## $ last          <chr> "Hillary", "Donald", "Gary", "Darrell", "Rocky", "Monica", "Jill", "Hillary", "Donald", "Gary", "Darrell...
## $ fips          <chr> "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "55001", "55001", "55001", "55001", "55001", "55001", "55001", "55003...
## $ name          <chr> "Wisconsin", "Wisconsin", "Wisconsin", "Wisconsin", "Wisconsin", "Wisconsin", "Wisconsin", "Adams", "Ada...
## $ reporting     <chr> "100.0", "100.0", "100.0", "100.0", "100.0", "100.0", "100.0", "100.0", "100.0", "100.0", "100.0", "100....
```

Despite the ".xml" extension on the URL, it's not XML data. I also don't know what some of the columns actually are, but you can dig into that. Also, there's a whole other section of data:

```
WI;S;G;0;Wisconsin;X;100.0;X;;50885;;||WI269201108;Dem;1380496;46.8;;X;;;1|WI267231108;GOP;1479262;50.2;X;X;X;;2|WI270541108;Lib;87291;3.0;;X;;;3
WI;S;G;55001;Adams;X;100.0;X;;50885;;||WI269201108;Dem;4093;41.2;;X;;;1|WI267231108;GOP;5346;53.9;X;X;X;;2|WI270541108;Lib;486;4.9;;X;;;3
WI;S;G;55003;Ashland;X;100.0;X;;50885;;||WI269201108;Dem;4349;55.1;;X;;;1|WI267231108;GOP;3337;42.2;X;X;X;;2|WI270541108;Lib;214;2.7;;X;;;3
WI;S;G;55005;Barron;X;100.0;X;;50885;;||WI269201108;Dem;8691;38.8;;X;;;1|WI267231108;GOP;12863;57.4;X;X;X;;2|WI270541108;Lib;853;3.8;;X;;;3
WI;S;G;55007;Bayfield;X;100.0;X;;50885;;||WI269201108;Dem;5161;54.6;;X;;;1|WI267231108;GOP;4022;42.6;X;X;X;;2|WI270541108;Lib;263;2.8;;X;;;3
WI;S;G;55009;Brown;X;100.0;X;;50885;;||WI269201108;Dem;51004;40.0;;X;;;1|WI267231108;GOP;71750;56.3;X;X;X;;2|WI270541108;Lib;4615;3.6;;X;;;3
WI;S;G;55011;Buffalo;X;100.0;X;;50885;;||WI269201108;Dem;2746;39.9;;X;;;1|WI267231108;GOP;3850;56.0;X;X;X;;2|WI270541108;Lib;285;4.1;;X;;;3
WI;S;G;55013;Burnett;X;100.0;X;;50885;;||WI269201108;Dem;3143;37.4;;X;;;1|WI267231108;GOP;4998;59.5;X;X;X;;2|WI270541108;Lib;258;3.1;;X;;;3
```

which obviously means something for that page (it's kinda obvious, but I'm so weary from the election that I'm kinda done with the data) and you can process in similar fashion as what is above.

Comment: Thanks. First, I'm so not an expert with webpages that I never would have known this was an XHR request. Second, the URL in the first line of code after calling the packages... where did you dig that up. I feel like this is something i used to know how to do but couldn't find anything in the source code. That would help tremendously as I'm pulling data from multiple states.

Comment: Using Chrome (other browsers have it, too, but less overtly) Inspect the page and then refresh it. Then, on the Network tab of the inspector window, click "XHR" in the row below the tabs. You'll see this in there. I suspect this code will work for all the states (with some tweaks for state abbreviations) since they have front-end javascript that is reading it and thus it shld need to be uniform. Post an addendum if not. This particular wrangling was kinda fun, especially seeing the warped mind of the devs who created this format :-)

Comment: I'd also prbly run `readr::type_convert()` on the `results` data frame to get proper types.

Comment: A) Think I got it in Firebug. B) Duh, I feel so stupid. I thought the '20161108' after 'WI_' in the URL was some unique identifier I was going to have to find for each state. No, it's just the date of the election. C) Thank you. Saved me a ton of time.